# Hibernate and PostgreSQL: REPEATABLE_READ and use of @Version annotation to avoid write skews and other phenomena

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-transactions, isolation-level

I'm using `Isolation.REPEATABLE_READ` to copy a large entity graph in a Spring Boot application. It basically executes SELECTs and INSERTs. I also employ optimistic locking using `@Version` annotation on all of the sub-entities. I see that even if I try to change something in the entity graph during the copy execution, the latter continues as if nothing happened. Let's assume that business-wise, this is accepted. According to SQL-92 Standard, the phenomena that are possible to happen are:

- Dirty Read
- Non-Repeatable Read
- Phantom Read

Four additional ones (A Critique of ANSI SQL Isolation Levels: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/tr-95-51.pdf):

- Dirty Write
- Read Skew
- Write Skew
- Lost Update

As far as I know, using repeatable read on PostgreSQL, only write skew is possible. But with optimistic locking, no inconsistencies occur. Is this thought correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> using repeatable read on PostgreSQL, only write skew is possible

Correct.

> But with optimistic locking, no inconsistencies occur.

No, that is not correct. You can get “write skew” with optimistic locking:

```
CREATE TABLE worker (
   name text,
   on_duty boolean,
   version bigint DEFAULT 0
);

INSERT INTO worker (name, on_duty) VALUES
   ('alice', TRUE),
   ('bob', TRUE);
```

Now two transactions work on the table:

```
Transaction 1                             Transaction 2

BEGIN ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;

SELECT name, version FROM worker WHERE on_duty;

 name  │ version 
═══════╪═════════
 alice │       0
 bob   │       0
(2 rows)

                                          BEGIN ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;

                                          SELECT name, version FROM worker WHERE on_duty;

                                           name  │ version 
                                          ═══════╪═════════
                                           alice │       0
                                           bob   │       0
                                          (2 rows)

                                          UPDATE worker
                                          SET on_duty = FALSE, version = version + 1
                                          WHERE name = 'bob' AND version = 0;

                                          COMMIT;

UPDATE worker
SET on_duty = FALSE, version = version + 1
WHERE name = 'alice' AND version = 0;

COMMIT;
```

Both transactions succeed, but you got write skew.

Comment: So, Transaction 1 never sees that Bob is not on duty, right?

Comment: Right. `REPEATABLE READ` implies that you will still see the same results for `SELECT name, version FROM worker WHERE on_duty;`, even though a concurrent transaction has modified the value and committed. I realize that I have made a typo in my answer; one of the transactions should update Alice.

Comment: Yes, I can clearly see the write skew now!